# Get rid of Console command line

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have created a c# console application with my classes.

Now I added a Form to draw my Figures. But when I launch application it launches both console and form.

How do I get rid of console command line and show only the form?

Main Class:

```
namespace Laba2
{
    static class Program
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We don't know becasue we don't see __any__ of your code..

Comment: @TaW not sure it's code specific...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Project` -> `(ProjectName) Properties` -> `Application` tab and change `Output type` from `Console Application` to `Windows Application`.